# How do I solve/get around this 'Gas estimation failed' error in my smart contract?

Tags: solidity, remix

It appears after I compile, deploy the contract on remix (using Rinkeby test network), and call the JoinDXCon( ) method using any string "foo".

Here's the error:

[image: Gas estimation failed]

And here's the smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Home {

    address[] public deployedConferences;
    address[] public members;
    uint public totalMembers;

    event JoinedDXCon(address indexed memAddr, string name);

    function createConference(string _confName) public {
        address newConference = new Conference(_confName, msg.sender);
        deployedConferences.push(newConference);
    }

    function getDeployedConferences() public view returns(address[]) {
        return deployedConferences;
    }

    function joinDXCon(string _name) public {
        members[totalMembers] = msg.sender;
        totalMembers++;

        emit JoinedDXCon(msg.sender, _name);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an error with your javascript, not with the contract. Can you share how you are calling this function?

Answer (score 2):

This fails because your array has a size of zero, so trying to assign `members[totalMembers]` will cause a revert.

Either use a mapping of uint to address, use `members.push()` to append to the array and resize it, or resize the array first, and then assign the value.